# Replacing user input in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to replace a user input into a dictionary in python 3.3...How is that done ? I have already tried `string.replace`.

```
symbols{}
letters{}

symbol=input(enter a symbol: )
letter=input(enter a letter assigned with your symbol: )
```

I the user input to be replaced into the dictionaries, how do I do that?

Comment: This is not valid Python code; can you please post your *actual* code?

Comment: You mean you want to add `symbol` and `letter` into the dictionaries? Why not just use the `symbols[key] = value` syntax?

Comment: well no, because I am making a puzzle and as the player develops through the puzzle this option will enable them to to remove from the dictionary so would you be able to tell me the command used to remove items from dictionaries please?

Comment: Sorry, this is all rather basic Python functionality. Have you read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) at all yet?

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway Martijn Pieters, as I say I am very new to this and I am having small issues, Thanks anyway !